# How to call this CGAL's QT interface function correctly?

Tags: c++, qt, cgal

My environment is CGAL 4.5 and QT5 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I am learning how to use CGAL's [Qt interface](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/GraphicsView/index.html) to render geometrical objectslike points, lines, segments. There don't seem to be an examples using this framework online so I am struggling at the moment.

I can't seem to get my test code to work. It compiles but throws a seg-fault.

Here is my code from my `MainWindow.cpp` file in my QTwidgets application created through QtCreator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Qt/PointsGraphicsItem.h>
#include <CGAL/Qt/SegmentsGraphicsItem.h>
#include <vector>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point_2;
typedef Kernel::Segment_2 Segment_2;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    std::vector<Point_2> pts;

    pts.push_back(Point_2(1,1));
    pts.push_back(Point_2(10,10));

    CGAL::Qt::PointsGraphicsItem< std::vector<Point_2> > graphical_points(&pts);

}
```

The last line seems to be the problem line. My code keeps throwing a segfault 
at this point. The message being

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.

Signal name :    SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : Segmentation fault
```

What am I doing wrong in this function call? I know I have to add the points to the graphics scene, but that is not important at the moment.

Ideally when the code, runs, it should display two points, one at (1,1) and the other at (10,10) once I add these points to the scene.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/LUTFQ8xA) is the link to the full `PointsGraphicsItem.h` file on Pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the graphics item with new and an empty vector of points, and call `scene.addItem(..)`.    When populating the vector with points, emit a signal after having connected it to `PointsGraphicsItem::modelChanged()`

If I was you, I would take an existing demo such as the Polygon_2 demo
and modifiy it little by little.

Note that the demos are not where we put the effort, as CGAL is mainly about the geometric data structures and algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now I see where the problem of your code is.  The life time of the vector `pts` is just the constructor `MainWindow::MainWindow(..)`.
When the paint method of the `PointsGraphicsItem` tries to draw these points, they are no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGAL::Qt::PointsGraphicsItem< std::vector<Point_2> > graphical_points(&pts);
```

In the above line you are passing the address of the local variable `pts`. Which is not allowed. Also don't forget to set the following flags in your `.pro` project file.

```
LIBS += -lCGAL -lgmp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -frounding-math
```